# Find contour/edge in pcolor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour, edge-detection

I'm trying to make a contour that follows the edges of the 'pixels' in a `pcolor` plot in Matlab. This is probably best explained in pictures. Here is a plot of my data. There is a distinct boundary between the yellow data (data==1) and the blue data (data==0):

[image: Pcolor plot]

Note that this is a `pcolor` plot so each 'square' is essentially a pixel. I want to return a contour that follows the *faces* of the yellow data *pixels*, **not** just the edge of the yellow data.

[image: i want this output]

So the output contour (green line) passes through the mid-points of the face (red dots) of the pixels.

Note that I don't want the contour to follow the centre points of the data (black dots), which would do something like this green line. This could be achieved easily with `contour`.

[image: I don't want this outcome]

Also, if it's any help, I have a few grids which may be useful. I have the points in the middle of the pixels (obviously, as that's what I've plotted here), I also have the points on the corners, AND I have the points on the west/east faces and the north/south faces. IF you're familiar with [Arakawa grids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arakawa_grids), this is an Arakawa-C grid, so I have the rho-, u-, v- and psi- points.

I've tried interpolation, interweaving grids, and a few other things but I'm not having any luck. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated and would stop me going crazy.

Cheers, Dave

EDIT:

Sorry, I simplified the images to make what I was trying to explain more obvious, but here is a larger (zoomed out) image of the region I'm trying to separate:
[image: zoomed out image]

As you can see, it's a complex outline which heads in a "southwest" direction before wrapping around and moving back "northeast". And here is the red line that I'd like to draw, through the black points:

[image: intended output line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a couple of modifications to [a solution I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230034/52738) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45203862/52738). I used a section of the sample image mask in the question for `data`. First, you will need to fill the holes in the mask, which you can do using [`imfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) from the the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html):

```
x = 1:15;  % X coordinates for pixels
y = 1:17;  % Y coordinates for pixels
mask = imfill(data, 'holes');
```

Next, apply the method from my other answer to compute an ordered set of outline coordinates (positioned on the pixel corners):

```
% Create raw triangulation data:
[cx, cy] = meshgrid(x, y);
xTri = bsxfun(@plus, [0; 1; 1; 0], cx(mask).');
yTri = bsxfun(@plus, [0; 0; 1; 1], cy(mask).');
V = [xTri(:) yTri(:)];
F = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, [1; 2; 3; 1; 3; 4], 0:4:(4*nnz(mask)-4)), 3, []).';

% Trim triangulation data:
[V, ~, Vindex] = unique(V, 'rows');
V = V-0.5;
F = Vindex(F);

% Create triangulation and find free edge coordinates:
TR = triangulation(F, V);
freeEdges = freeBoundary(TR).';
xOutline = V(freeEdges(1, [1:end 1]), 1);  % Ordered edge x coordinates
yOutline = V(freeEdges(1, [1:end 1]), 2);  % Ordered edge y coordinates
```

Finally, you can get the desired coordinates at the centers of the pixel edges like so:

```
ex = xOutline(1:(end-1))+diff(xOutline)./2;
ey = yOutline(1:(end-1))+diff(yOutline)./2;
```

And here's a plot showing the results:

```
imagesc(x, y, data);
axis equal
set(gca, 'XLim', [0.5 0.5+size(mask, 2)], 'YLim', [0.5 0.5+size(mask, 1)]);
hold on;
plot(ex([1:end 1]), ey([1:end 1]), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(ex, ey, 'k.', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer, and it's a very different direction then I would have taken. My answer works for my problem, but your answer seems much clearer - so I've accepted yours!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following code:

```
% plotting some data:
data = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1];
p = pcolor(data);
axis ij
% compute the contour
x = size(data,2)-cumsum(data,2)+1;
x = x(:,end);
y = (1:size(data,1));
% compute the edges shift
Y = get(gca,'YTick');
y_shift = (Y(2)-Y(1))/2;
% plot it:
hold on
plot(x,y+y_shift,'g','LineWidth',3,'Marker','o',...
    'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerEdgeColor','none')
```

It produces this:

[image]

Is this what you look for?

The most important lines above is:

```
x = size(data,2)-cumsum(data,2)+1;
x = x(:,end);
```

which finds the place of shifting between 0 to 1 for every row (**assuming there is only one in a row**).

Then, within the `plot` I shift `y` by half of the distance between two adjacent y-axis tick, so they will be placed at the center of the edge.

---

EDIT:

After some trials with this kind of data, I have got this result:

```
imagesc(data);
axis ij
b = bwboundaries(data.','noholes');
x = b{1}(:,1);
y = b{1}(:,2);
X = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,x,[0 -0.5 0.5]),[],1);
Y = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,y,[0 0.5 -0.5]),[],1);
k = boundary(X,Y,1);
hold on
plot(X(k),Y(k),'g','LineWidth',3,'Marker','o',...
    'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerEdgeColor','none')
```

It's not perfect, but may get you closer to what you want in a more simple approach:

[image]

Comment: Very nice suggestion, but unfortunately the input data is a bit more complex :( (See edit). But possibly your excellent suggestion won't work where the line between the data points is horizontal, like in the new pictures I added?

Comment: @David_G Sorry for the _too_ specific solution, but now I have to clarify some things -
 Is the new image is all the image? Is there is only one yellow region surrounded by blue? In other words, how do you define where the red line should be plotted? Why there is no red line in the blue hole in the middle?

Comment: the new image is a zoom in of the full matrix. The yellow region effectively defines the mask where land/water exists. So yellow(==1) is water, blue(==0) is land. I want the boundary between. There is a large yellow region with some blue along the southern edge, and some isolated blue pockets. It's not critical to capture that isolated blue hole you describe. If you do draw a red line around that as well, that's ok. Hope that helps.

Comment: @David_G sorry for the delay, I had no time to go back to this. See my edit for another partial try.

Comment: I'm not getting a close enough result with your image toolbox method. That being said, THANK YOU for opening my eyes to it! I haven't used bwboundaries, etc before but it looks very powerful. I want to tick your answer or give you bonus points just for this at least!

Comment: @David_G you welcome. I have no time to continue working on that right now, but you may get the best solution if you combine the two approaches. Use your method to identify all the points (marked as red x in your answer), and then use `boundary` to connect them. The only issue left is to discard the blue 'islands'. If I'll have more time soon I'll try to get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've solved it... well close enough to be happy.

First I take the original data (which I call `mask_rho` and use this to make masks `mask_u`, `mask_v`, which is similar to `mask_rho` but is shifted slightly in the horizontal and vertical directions, respectively.

```
%make mask_u and mask_v  
for i = 2:size(mask_rho,2)
for j = 1:size(mask_rho,1)
    mask_u(j, i-1) = mask_rho(j, i) * mask_rho(j, i-1);
end
end
for i = 1:size(mask_rho,2)
for j = 2:size(mask_rho,1)
    mask_v(j-1, i) = mask_rho(j, i) * mask_rho(j-1, i);
end
end
```

I then make modified masks `mask_u1` and `mask_v1` which are the same as `mask_rho` but averaged with the neighbouring points in the horizontal and vertical directions, respectively.

```
%make mask which is shifted E/W (u) and N/S (v)
mask_u1 = (mask_rho(1:end-1,:)+mask_rho(2:end,:))/2;
mask_v1 = (mask_rho(:,1:end-1)+mask_rho(:,2:end))/2;
```

Then I use the difference between the masks to locate places where the masks change from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 in the horizontal direction (in the u mask) and in the vertical direction (in the v mask).

```
% mask_u-mask_u1 gives the NEXT row with a change from 0-1.
diff_mask_u=logical(mask_u-mask_u1);
lon_u_bnds=lon_u.*double(diff_mask_u);
lon_u_bnds(lon_u_bnds==0)=NaN;
lat_u_bnds=lat_u.*double(diff_mask_u);
lat_u_bnds(lat_u_bnds==0)=NaN;
lon_u_bnds(isnan(lon_u_bnds))=[];
lat_u_bnds(isnan(lat_u_bnds))=[];
%now same for changes in mask_v
diff_mask_v=logical(mask_v-mask_v1);
lon_v_bnds=lon_v.*double(diff_mask_v);
lon_v_bnds(lon_v_bnds==0)=NaN;
lat_v_bnds=lat_v.*double(diff_mask_v);
lat_v_bnds(lat_v_bnds==0)=NaN;
lon_v_bnds(isnan(lon_v_bnds))=[];
lat_v_bnds(isnan(lat_v_bnds))=[];
bnd_coords_cat = [lon_u_bnds,lon_v_bnds;lat_u_bnds,lat_v_bnds]'; %make into 2 cols, many rows
```

And the result grabs all the coordinates at the edges of the boundary:

[image: mostly solved..]

Now my answer goes a bit awry. If I plot the above vector as points `plot(bnd_coords_cat(:,1),bnd_coords_cat(:,2),'kx'` I get the above image, which is fine. However, if I join the line, as in: `plot(bnd_coords_cat(:,1),bnd_coords_cat(:,2),'-'` then the line jumps around, as the points aren't sorted. When I do the sort (using `sort` and `pdist2`) to sort by closest points, Matlab sometimes chooses odd points... nevertheless I figured I'd include this code as an appendix, and optional extra. Someone may know a better way to sort the output vector`bnds_coords_cat`:

```
% now attempt to sort
[~,I]=sort([lon_u_bnds,lon_v_bnds]);
bnd_coords_inc1 = bnd_coords_cat(I,1);
bnd_coords_inc2 = bnd_coords_cat(I,2);
bnd_coords = [bnd_coords_inc1,bnd_coords_inc2];
bnd_coords_dist = pdist2(bnd_coords,bnd_coords);
bnd_coords_sort = nan(1,size(bnd_coords,1));
bnd_coords_sort(1)=1;
for ii=2:size(bnd_coords,1)
 bnd_coords_dist(:,bnd_coords_sort(ii-1)) = Inf; %don't go backwards?
 [~,closest_idx] = min(bnd_coords_dist(bnd_coords_sort(ii-1),:));
 bnd_coords_sort(ii)=closest_idx;
end
bnd_coords_final(:,1)=bnd_coords(bnd_coords_sort,1);
bnd_coords_final(:,2)=bnd_coords(bnd_coords_sort,2);
```

Note that the `pdist2` method was suggested by a colleague and also from this SO answer, [Sort coordinates points in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631934/sort-coordinates-points-in-matlab). This is the final result:

[image: OK, sorting is a bit stuffed up]

To be honest, plotting without the line is fine. So as far as I'm concerned this is close enough to be answered!

Comment: This method worked for me - so I would say that this answer is good. However, it's a bit awkward, whereas @gnovice's answer is a bit clearer, so I will accept that answer.